# Re-reserve Windows 10 upgrade?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

Can you re-reserve a Windows 10 upgrade after cancelling?  One of my family members clicked on the reservation before I could apply an upgrade, and reserving 10 seems to have disabled the ability to run the Windows Anytime Upgrade tool.  I wanted to upgrade a copy of Windows 7 so that I can reserve a higher version of Windows 10, but I'm afraid if I cancel the reservation it won't let me re-reserve.

Comment: Assuming they didn't lie about free upgrades for a year, the "reservation" shouldn't do anything: you should still be able to upgrade for free regardless.

Comment: Yea, but it's Microsoft. They're weird.  e.g. Why are they putting a time limit on the free upgrade?  Who knows?

Comment: @Keegan Because how else are they gonna get money? Start selling user data? Ever more intrusive adverts? While there is no such thing as a free lunch, the reservation system does imply that they won't go down THAT route (much more than they already are...)

Comment: @topherg I wasn't suggesting it should be free for everyone forever, just that Windows gets most of its revenue & marketshare from OEM, so whether the offer expires shouldn't make a _big_ difference. I won't bash MS on SU, but suffice it to say the offer is unusual for MS and it's understandable for users to be a little dubious.

Comment: @Keegan oh definitely, but then again, I guess they really want to move away from what they were into something new, and don't want anyone left in the digital dark ages (i know many people who still use XP, and one lunatic who insists that 2000 is the best OS ever)

Answer (score 1):

Didn't Google far enough.  A Microsoft answer to another [question](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/frequently-asked-questions-windows-10/5c0b9368-a9e8-4238-b1e4-45f4b7ed2fb9) was

> Can I change the email address used to reserve the free upgrade?
>
> > You have to cancel the reservation and reserve Windows 10 again if you want it to a different email address.

Given that, I think I shouldn't have to worry about cancelling and re-registering.  And Windows SuperSite [confirms](http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/successfully-cancelling-your-windows-10-upgrade-reservation) this.

Comment: Just did this. After you cancel, you are given a "I changed my mind" option

Comment: @topherg Thanks for comment. I did this last month without any issue, just forgot to add a confirmation to my answer.